#  Missing summary tags for explicitly implemented interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, sandcastle, xml-documentation

Basically, I have the following code:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    /// <summary> My Summary </summary>
    void MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> { ... }
}
```

MyProject.XML

```
<member name="M:MyProject.MyDictionary`2.System#Collection#Generic#ICollection{System#Collections#Generic#KeyValuePair{TKey@TValue}}#Clear">
 <summary>
  My Summary
 </summary>
</member>
```

Sandcastle's Built Output:

> > Warn: ShowMissingComponent: Missing  documentation for M:MyProject.MyDictionary`2.System#Collections#Generic#ICollection{T}#Clear

So, not sure what to do here exactly. I did have my Sandcastle Build Options include explicit implementations, which is why it creates a page for them in the documentation, but it can't seem to figure out that I **did** create XML Comments for this method. Oddly enough, the `void MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKek key, TValue value)` method is identified as having XML Comments. In fact, all of the implicitly implemented ICollection> methods are giving Sandcastle an issue. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure that you tried everything, and I know that you want to know how to do it, but I think it's impossible. It's bug in Sandcastle, and it isn't fixed still.. :(

http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/workitem/5594

Comment: This makes sense now since Sandcastle is expecting it to be `M:MyProject.MyDictionary`2.System#Collections#Generic#ICollection{T}#Clear` and VS.NET compiled it with the full name instead of `T`.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your project is building the xml documentation file. There is a check box in the project properties to build the xml file.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned that there is an xml file generated. Hopefully this answer helps someone else even if it's not the issue you're having.

Comment: You do need to add a reference to the XML document in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, did you try this?:

```
/// <summary>
/// My Summary 
/// </summary>
```

Yes, I know it means the same thing, but it could be a parsing issue.

Comment: Alright, I had to ask. Sometimes parsers are really dumb about simple things like this.

Comment: Additionally, I would have thought your void should be public since it is a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue caused by caching. There were changes in Sandcastle that require that the old cache files be deleted with the new release.  If not already deleted, they may be causing a problem.  You can find out where to find the cache files and delete them in the [release notes](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/ef1dba5d-bb3b-4d27-9ccf-6f1ec8d1e793.htm) in the Breaking Changes section.